# search file from document directory in ios

Tags: xcode, swift

I have enabled itune file sharing in my Application.
I have added pdf file in my application directory.
now I want to search that file using my app. and upload it on server.
also if there multiple file and folder I want to show in application. search folder and select specific file and upload it. please suggest best way for doing that.

Appriciate for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
        do
        {
            let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
            print(dirPaths)
            let Pnames = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(dirPaths) as [String]
            var ProductImgs:Array<String> = Array<String>()
            var ProductNames:Array<String> = Array<String>()

            for name in Pnames
            {
                let fileName:String = name

                if fileName.hasSuffix(".pdf")
                {
                    PdfURLs.append(dirPaths.stringByAppendingString("/\(fileName)"))
                    PdfNames.append(fileName)
                    print(dirPaths.stringByAppendingString("/\(fileName)"))
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine using third party libraries, it would be great to use **Alamofire**. It is an HTTP networking library written in Swift.

You can upload the file easily using this one,

```
let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Default", withExtension: "png")
Alamofire.upload(.POST, "https://httpbin.org/post", file: fileURL)
```

For a complete understanding of this library check out this link, https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire